# Struggling with Realm Data Structure on SwiftUI app

Tags: arrays, database, xcode, swiftui, realm

I am new to data persistence on SwiftUI and have decided to give Realm a go.
So far I am able to create a simple to do list app with CRUD operations, but I'm struggling to scale it up to manage more complex data sets.

I am building a small writing app that needs to allow the user to create multiple stories step by step. Each story should have its own array of characters, plots, locations, etc.

So basically, I've created a Story class that refers to other classes (Realm objects):

```
class Story: Object, Identifiable {

@objc dynamic var id : Date = Date()
@objc dynamic var warmUp: WarmUp = WarmUp()
@objc dynamic var settings: Settings = Settings()
@objc dynamic var characters = StoryCharacter()
@objc dynamic var world: World = World()
@objc dynamic var locations = Location()
@objc dynamic var plots = Plot()
@objc dynamic var scenes = StoryScene()
@objc dynamic var ideas = Idea()}
```

But I am unable to figure out how to store an array of objects without making the app constantly crash.

I've tried:

```
List<Object>(), RealmSwift.List<Object>(), [Object](), etc
```

But all of those make my app crash whenever I'm trying to build it.

Any ideas? + Am I taking the right approach according to you regarding how I'm planning to store my app's data?

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: have you tried : List<Story>()

Comment: This is the same as List<Location>() or any other subclasses, crash.

Comment: can you show (the code) where you actually write to realm

Answer (score 0):

A List object is defined like this

```
let myList = List<YourRealmObject>()
```

A List object is not an array - while that have similar interfaces, there are some fundamental differences as well.

For example a List can be used to created a relationship and LinkingObjects object can be used to create an inverse relationship. List objects are also live updating - so if an element in the list is updated (say, by another user), the List will reflect that update

Lists are also collections and can be observed for events of the child objects, which is a little different than an Array.

Also note that as of this writing, there are some issues with Lists that store Primitives - for example the `@count` aggregate function does not function on primitives - the child objects need to be wrapped in a supported Realm Object to use @count.